# How to access base class member variable in some other class

Tags: delphi

To simplify my problem i am quoting an class like this

```
Base = class;
public:
 Name: String;
end;

Derived = class(Base)
public:
 Name: String;
end;


Procedure Book.DoSomething;
Var
str: String;
Begin
 str := derivObj.Name; //I need base class Name not the Derived one
End;
```

i am very much new to Delphi so please help me out.

Comment: You can access it by typecast like `Base(derivObj).Name`, but it's a bad practice and wrong design.

Comment: @Jeeva - ... so you could edit your question to tell us why you need this, and maybe someone comes up with a better design ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To access to parent class member:
    str := Base(derivObj).Name;

Comment: This is the exact the same as TLama answer's, no?

Comment: @RBA But TLama did not answer, and only posted a comment.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - Indeed it is a comment. And I got also the TLama's comment about the reason. So the user2696546 got the points :)